# NaN error for gaussian random distribution

Tags: java, random, distribution, nan, gaussian

I get random NaN between my outputs.

```
Random Temp:61.816288952756864 'F
Random Temp:NaN 'F
Random Temp:NaN 'F
Random Temp:63.674960517071916 'F
Random Temp:NaN 'F
Random Temp:62.581425292320894 'F
Random Temp:58.21928355494033 'F
Random Temp:60.00714587886456 'F
Random Temp:NaN 'F
Random Temp:60.62983167247955 'F
Random Temp:62.74961457200155 'F
Random Temp:58.50731966210792 'F
Random Temp:NaN 'F
Random Temp:55.20026299393227 'F
```

Here is my code:

```
public static double gaussRandom(double dAverage, double dStddev, Random timeRand){
    double iRandom1, iRandom2;
    double dRandom1, dRandom2, result;

    //iRandom1 = timeRand.nextInt();
    //dRandom1 = (double)iRandom1 /2147483647;
    //iRandom2 = timeRand.nextInt();
    //dRandom2 = (double)iRandom2 /2147483647;

    iRandom1 = timeRand.nextInt();
    dRandom1 = (double)iRandom1 /2147483647.0;
    iRandom2 = timeRand.nextInt();
    dRandom2 = (double)iRandom2 /2147483647.0;

    result = dAverage + dStddev * Math.sqrt(-2.0* Math.log(dRandom1))*Math.cos(6.28318531*dRandom2);

    return result;
}

public static void main(String [] args){

    int i, liSampleSize;
    double dAverage, dStddev, result;

    System.out.println("==========================\n");
    System.out.println("Gaussian numbers generator\n");
    System.out.println("==========================\n");

    liSampleSize = 24*4; // 24 hours every 15 mins;
    dAverage = 60; //Average temp;
    dStddev = 2; //standard deviation of 20;

    Random myRand = new Random();
    myRand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for(i = 0; i<liSampleSize;i++)
    {
        result = gaussRandom(dAverage,dStddev,myRand);
        System.out.println("Random Temp:"+ result +" 'F");
    }


}
```

How can I fix this code so it doesn't generate NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `dRandom1` can be negative, while real logarithms only take arguments from `(0, +inf)`

Comment: I think you meant (0, +inf] where 0 is exclusive.

Comment: @jaket My left bound is correct, as to the right bound I disagree with including +inf since it's not an element of the set of real numbers (however when using IEEE754 it might make some sense).

Comment: log(0) is -inf and log(+inf) is +inf.  Technically both are legit according to IEEE754. Without having really studied the OPs code I would assume he would want to avoid inf for the same reason he wants to avoid NaN.

Comment: I agree, however I thought that providing the reason for error on the higher level (mathematical) would produce a cleaner answer, since the reason for error was located in the mathematical logic of the erroneous statement, rather than due to the representation (since no representation of the real number set would help).